# Hibernate retrieves only first record from database, rest is null

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have a uni project that is intended to log sales and, based on a set of pre established rules, determine which of them are eligible for four kinds of aditionals: two bonuses (specific product and sales by salesman) and two prizes (product campaign and best salesman).
It is written using Java (Spring Framework), and uses Hibernate to communicate with a MySql database and JSP for the presentation layer.
While testing it I found that something to the sales bonus is not working properly. Even though the calculation is performed successfully and the results stored in the database, when trying to retrieve them I get a null value.

For instance, when performing the calculation the result shown in the jsp is

```
From      |    To     |  Salesman   |      Bonus       |             Prizes
                                    | Sales | Product  | Best salesman | Campaign
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01/01/2013  22/11/2013   Salesman 1    No      No          No          No
01/01/2013  22/11/2013   Salesman 2    Yes     Yes         No          Yes
01/01/2013  22/11/2013   Salesman 3    Yes     Yes         No          No
01/01/2013  22/11/2013   Salesman 4    No      No          No          No
```

but after refreshing it, which involves getting the results from the database, it only shows

```
From      |    To     |  Salesman   |      Bonus       |             Prizes
                                    | Sales | Product  | Best salesman | Campaign
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01/01/2013  22/11/2013  Salesman 2    Yes      Yes          No        Yes
01/01/2013  22/11/2013  Salesman 3    No       Yes          No         No
```

And if I check the SalesBonus table via PHPMyAdmin I get

```
id   dateCreation    dateFrom     dateTo    total  units salesman_id
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1     2014-02-05    2013-01-01  2013-11-22   200     1      2
4     2014-02-05    2013-01-01  2013-11-22   200     3      3
```

Futhermore, if I run using Debug, the variables tree shows

```
AllBonuses ArrayList<E> (id=491)
    elementData Object[3] (id=502)
        [0] Aditional (id=503)
            productCampaignRegistry Prize (id=506)
            ProductBonus PersistentBag (id=507)
            salesBonusRegistry SalesBonus (id=508)
            dateCreation Timestamp (id=509)
            dateFrom Timestamp (id=510)
            dateTo Timestamp (id=511)
            id 1
            bestSalesman null
            salesman Salesman (id=512)
                active true
                lastname "Noble" (id=513)
                id 2 
                name "Donna" (id=514)
        [1] Aditional (id=504)
            productCampaignRegistry null
            ProductBonus PersistentBag (id=515)
            SalesBonusRegistry null (should be id 4 in the SalesBonus table)
            dateCreation Timestamp (id=516)
            dateFrom Timestamp (id=517)
            dateTo Timestamp (id=518)
            id 2
            bestSalesman null
            salesman Salesman (id=519)
                active true
                lastname "Dent" (id=520)
                id 3
                name "Arthur" (id=521)
```

which means that the SalesBonus registry shown in the bonuses table has been stored, but somehow it does not appear when retrieving the Aditional registry where it belongs.

To make sure it was an issue I deleted the entire database, created it again, inserted a new Salesman and Sales and performed the calculation so that it should insert a new SalesBonus registry. Unfortunately, the issue repeated.

The classes are these

```
@Entity
public class Aditional implements Serializable {
@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@Column(nullable=false)
private Date dateCreation;
@Column(nullable=false)
private Date dateFrom;
@Column(nullable=false)
private Date dateTo;
@ManyToOne
private Salesman salesman;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private SalesBonus salesBonusRegistry;
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<ProductBonus> productBonuses;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Prize bestSalesman;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
private Prize productCampaign;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class Bonus implements Serializable {
@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private int id;
@Column(nullable=false)
private Date dateCreation;
@Column(nullable=false)
private Date dateFrom;
@Column(nullable=false)
private Date dateTo;
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
private Salesman salesman;
@Column(nullable=false)
private int units=0;
@Column(nullable=false)
private float total=0;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="S")
public class SalesBonus extends Bonus{
@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Sale> elements;
```

The get method used in the servlet in question is

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
setUser((User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user"));
if (getUser()==null)
{
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login");
return;
}

if (!checkRole(getUser()))
{
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/error");
return;
}
request.setAttribute("salesmen", service.getActiveSalesmen());
request.setAttribute("products", service.getProducts());
request.setAttribute("aditionals", service.getAditionals());
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/ComputeAditionals.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

This is the method used in the service layer to retrieve the Aditional registries

```
@Override
public ArrayList<Aditional> getAditionals() {
ArrayList<Aditional> all = dataAccess.getAditionals();

for (Aditional aditional : all)
{
if (aditional.getCampaign()!=null && aditional.getCampaign().getProduct()==null)
aditional.setCampaign(null);

if (aditional.getBestSalesman()!=null && aditional.getBestSalesman().getProduct()!=null)
aditional.setBestSalesman(null);
}
return all;
}
```

This is the method used in the DataAcessHibernateTemplate

```
@Override
public ArrayList<Aditional> getAditionals()
{
return (ArrayList<Aditional>) this.hibernateTemplate.loadAll(Aditional.class);
}
```

And when trying to retrieve the ProductBonus registries it also uses this

```
@Override
public ProductBonus getProductBonus(Integer id)
{
return this.hibernateTemplate.get(ProductBonus.class, id);
}
```

Thanks in advanced!

Edit: this is the (slightly edited) SLF4j output I get when the Adicional registries are loaded

```
18:34:33,853 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:410 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
18:34:33,853 DEBUG ConnectionManager:444 - opening JDBC connection
18:34:33,881 DEBUG SQL:111 - 
select 
    this_.id as id5_6_, 
    this_.creationDate as creation2_5_6_, 
    this_.dateFrom as dateFrom5_6_, 
    this_.dateTo as dateTo5_6_, 
    this_.salesman_id as salesman5_5_6_,
    salesman2_.id as id3_0_,
    salesman2_.active as active3_0_,
    salesman2_.lastname as lastname3_0_,
    salesman2_.name as name3_0_,
    prize3_.id as id9_1_,
    prize3_.creationDate as creation2_9_1_,
    prize3_.dateFrom as dateFrom9_1_,
    prize3_.dateTo as dateTo9_1_,
    prize3_.total as total9_1_,
    prize3_.isCampaign as isCampaign9_1_,
    prize3_.prizeWinner_id as prizeWin7_9_1_,
    prize3_.product_id as product8_9_1_,
    salesman4_.id as id3_2_,
    salesman4_.active as active3_2_, 
    salesman4_.lastname as lastname3_2_,
    salesman4_.name as name3_2_, 
    product5_.id as id2_3_, 
    product5_.name as name2_3_, 
    product5_.costUnit as costUnit3_2_3_, 
    salesBonus6_.id as id6_4_, 
    salesBonus6_.creationDate as creation2_6_4_, 
    salesBonus6_.dateFrom as dateFrom6_4_, 
    salesBonus6_.dateTo as dateTo6_4_, 
    salesBonus6_.total as total6_4_, 
    salesBonus6_.units as units6_4_, 
    salesBonus6_.salesman_id as salesman7_6_4_, 
    salesman7_.id as id3_5_, 
    salesman7_.active as active3_5_, 
    salesman7_.lastname as lastname3_5_, 
    salesman7_.name as name3_5_ 
from 
  (Adicional this_ left outer join Salesman salesman2_ on 
    (this_.salesman_id=salesman2_.id left outer join Prize prize3_ on 
      (this_.id=prize3_.id left outer join Salesman salesman4_ on 
    (prize3_.prizeWinner_id=salesman4_.id left outer join Product product5_ on
      (prize3_.product_id=product5_.id left outer join SalesBonus salesBonus6_  on 
        (this_.id=salesBonus6_.id left outer join Salesman salesman7_ on salesBonus6_.salesman_id=salesman7_.id))))))

18:34:33,881 TRACE AbstractBatcher:513 - preparing statement
18:34:33,886 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:426 - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
18:34:33,890 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2] as column [id3_0_]
18:34:33,891 TRACE BasicExtractor:66 - found [null] as column [id9_1_]
18:34:33,891 TRACE BasicExtractor:66 - found [null] as column [id3_2_]
18:34:33,891 TRACE BasicExtractor:66 - found [null] as column [id2_3_]
18:34:33,892 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [1] as column [id6_4_]
18:34:33,892 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2] as column [id3_5_]
18:34:33,893 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [1] as column [id5_6_]
18:34:33,895 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [true] as column [active3_0_]
18:34:33,896 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [Noble] as column [lastname3_0_]
18:34:33,896 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [Donna] as column [name3_0_]
18:34:33,907 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2013-12-20 20:17:34.0] as column [creation2_6_4_]
18:34:33,908 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2013-01-01 00:00:00.0] as column [dateFrom6_4_]
18:34:33,908 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2013-11-22 00:00:00.0] as column [dateTo6_4_]
18:34:33,909 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [200.0] as column [total6_4_]
18:34:33,909 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [1] as column [units6_4_]
18:34:33,909 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2] as column [salesman7_6_4_]
18:34:33,910 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2013-12-20 20:17:34.0] as column [creation2_5_6_]
18:34:33,910 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2013-01-01 00:00:00.0] as column [dateFrom5_6_]
18:34:33,910 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2013-11-22 00:00:00.0] as column [dateTo5_6_]
18:34:33,910 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2] as column [salesman5_5_6_]
18:34:33,911 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [3] as column [id3_0_]
18:34:33,911 TRACE BasicExtractor:66 - found [null] as column [id9_1_]
18:34:33,911 TRACE BasicExtractor:66 - found [null] as column [id3_2_]
18:34:33,911 TRACE BasicExtractor:66 - found [null] as column [id2_3_]
18:34:33,911 TRACE BasicExtractor:66 - found [null] as column [id6_4_]
18:34:33,912 TRACE BasicExtractor:66 - found [null] as column [id3_5_]
18:34:33,912 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2] as column [id5_6_]
18:34:33,912 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [true] as column [active3_0_]
18:34:33,912 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [Dent] as column [lastname3_0_]
18:34:33,912 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [Arthur] as column [name3_0_]
18:34:33,913 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2013-12-20 20:17:34.0] as column [creation2_5_6_]
18:34:33,913 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2013-01-01 00:00:00.0] as column [dateFrom5_6_]
18:34:33,913 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [2013-11-22 00:00:00.0] as column [dateTo5_6_]
18:34:33,914 TRACE BasicExtractor:71 - found [3] as column [salesman5_5_6_]
18:34:33,914 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:433 - about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
18:34:33,914 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:418 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
18:34:33,914 TRACE AbstractBatcher:562 - closing statement
18:34:33,923 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:410 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
```

This makes me think that it may be something related to the sql query, although how could that explain the fact that only the first registry is loaded? =\

Comment: Holy code dump batman!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was a mapping issue. Adding a proper join column and remapping the database did the trick.

So, the modified Aditional class now is.

```
@Entity
public class Aditional implements Serializable {
@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
@Column(nullable=false)
private Date dateCreation;
@Column(nullable=false)
private Date dateFrom;
@Column(nullable=false)
private Date dateTo;
@ManyToOne
private Salesman salesman;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="salesBonus_id")
private SalesBonus salesBonusRegistry;
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<ProductBonus> productBonuses;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="salesmanPrize_id")
private Prize bestSalesman;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="campaignPrize_id")
private Prize productCampaign;
```